# Data in c++ with fopen and fread and fwrite

Tags: c++, codeblocks, fopen

i got a problem in saving data in c++ 
 it is my code :

////////////

if(ID/1000==20)
    {

```
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("c:\\data.dat","r");
    boss temp; 
    while(fread(&temp,sizeof(boss),1,f))
    {   cout<<temp.fname;   getch();


        if(temp.ID==ID&&temp.pass==Pass)
        {

            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(5,7);
            cout<<"welcome "<<temp.fname<<" "<<temp.lname;
            bosss=temp;
            user=1;
            Sleep(2000);
            break;
        }


    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

///////////////

i have a struct . the name is boss
i have two var from that type : temp and bosss

now my problem is the while is not work
but a day ago it was working well
and if i write fread alone without while it works well too
i got no idea what is the problem

i write this code on CodeBlocks

Comment: Post a COMPLETE program that we can compile. For example, we need to know what is in `boss`...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_P9arrELM7CRGxGNWJMVVoyWkk&authuser=0

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_P9arrELM7CcTF4cVhoMjVtUHM&authuser=0

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_P9arrELM7CaHRVZXdoMUEyaE0&authuser=0

Comment: they are my files . one c++ and two header

Comment: by the way for ID enter 20000 and for Pass enter 12345

Comment: Ehm, I meant you need to post your code as part of this question. If you post a link to some code that may be there now, gone tomorrow, it will help nobody else, and this is not a site where the purpose is to help individuals with their individual problem, per se, but to help the programming community with specific problems - the distinction being that "other people should also be able to recognise their problem" when they see your code, and use the answer(s) to help them.

Comment: @sass you have posted links to files that other people can't see!

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether `fread` returns a value other than `sizeof(boss)`, and if it does, call `ferror` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/)) to find out if there was an error.

Comment: sorry . i don't understand . could you explain more ?

Comment: when i wirte fread alone it works but in while it got problem but an hour ago it did not have any problem with while

Comment: The problem that occurs - can you let me know what it is?